# VS Code connecting to jupyterlab server not selecting kernel

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

We have recently moved to a JupyterLab Server from another IDE. We are trying to get VS Code hooked up so that we can code in it rather. After much struggle, we got VS Code to connect to our remote JupyterLab server. On the status bar in the bottom, it shows
[image]

However, as soon as we connect to the JupyerLab server, all the 'run' buttons on screen disappears.

[image]

We are getting no support from our IT and have to figure it out ourselves.
A colleague suspects that it (VS Code) is not picking up the python kernel from the server. How do we go about selecting it? or pointing to it?

An additional question, how do we see and browse the folders on the JupyterLab server in VS Code?

Appreciate any assistance

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you didn't really connect to the remote server.

1. Install [Remote-SSH](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh) extension. Then you can see the button on the bottom left. Click and you can connect to your service and view your folder.

[image]

[image]

You can read [document about Remote-SSH](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh-tutorial) for more details/

**Connect to a remote Jupyter server.**

According to the [document about jupyter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks#_connect-to-a-remote-jupyter-server), you have to do the following steps:

- Open the Kernel Picker button on the top right-hand side of the notebook (or run the Notebook: Select Notebook Kernel command from the Command Palette).

[image]

- Select the Existing Jupyter Server option to connect to an existing Jupyter server.

[image]

- To connect to an existing server for the first time, select Enter the URL of the running Jupyter server.

[image]

- When prompted to Enter the URL of the running Jupyter server, provide the server's URI (hostname) with the authentication token included with a ?token= URL parameter. (If you start the server in the VS Code terminal with an authentication token enabled, the URL with the token typically appears in the terminal output from where you can copy it.) Alternatively, you can specify a username and password after providing the URI.

[image]